# WPF. DataGrid. Sum of grouping elements without ListCollectionView.Refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, ivalueconverter

**Hello everyone!** I have a Class with PropertyChanged elements.

```
namespace PlChangeWeightings
{
    public class MyWeighting : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _CarNumber;
        public string CarNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return _CarNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                _CarNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CarNumber"));
            }
        }

        private DateTime _DateWeighting;
        public DateTime DateWeighting
        {
            get
            {
                return _DateWeighting;
            }
            set
            {
                _DateWeighting = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DateWeighting"));
            }
        }

        private bool _TypeWeighting;
        public bool TypeWeighting
        {
            get
            {
                return _TypeWeighting;
            }
            set
            {
                _TypeWeighting = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TypeWeighting"));
            }
        }

        private double _Mass;
        public double Mass
        {
            get
            {
                return _Mass;
            }
            set
            {
                _Mass = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Mass"));
            }
        }


        public bool _Selected;

        public bool Selected
        {
            get
            {
                return _Selected;
            }
            set
            {
                _Selected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Selected"));
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

In Code I have OdservableCollection of MyWeightings and ListCollectionView:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyWeighting> WeightingsList
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<MyWeighting>)GetValue(WeightingsListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(WeightingsListProperty, value); }
        }

        public ListCollectionView MyCollectionView { get; set; }

public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
 MyCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(WeightingsList);
                MyCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("CarNumber"));
                dataGrid1.ItemsSource = MyCollectionView;          
        }
```

ListCollectionView bind to ItemsSource of DataGrid. XAML:

```
<DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  IsReadOnly="False"  Grid.Row="1" Name="dataGrid1" FontSize="12" Background="#69D4D0C8" CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate x:Name="GrIt" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                            <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True" FontSize="13"
                                            Foreground="#FF3D3A2B" FontWeight="Regular" FontFamily="Calibri">
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                                            <Border.Background>
                                                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                                                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FF9FB9E2" />
                                                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFCAD6EB" />
                                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                            </Border.Background>
                                                        </Border>
                                                        <Label FontSize="13" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Calibri" Foreground="#FF3D3A2B" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                        <Label FontSize="13" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Calibri" Foreground="#FF3D3A2B" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Вагон №"/>
                                                        <Label FontSize="13" Grid.Column="3" FontFamily="Calibri" Foreground="#FF3D3A2B" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Items, Converter={StaticResource GroupConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                                        </Label>
                                                        <Label FontSize="13" Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Calibri" Foreground="#FF3D3A2B" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Масса нетто"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                                            </Expander>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

This was done for groupping elements in DataGrid. In group header I show  difference of 2 groupping elements due to converter:

```
public class GroupConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                var weights = value as IEnumerable<object>;
                if (weights == null)
                    return "";

                double brutto = 0;
                double tara = 0;

                foreach (var u in weights)
                {
                    if (((MyWeighting)u).Selected && ((MyWeighting)u).TypeWeighting)
                        tara = ((MyWeighting)u).Mass;
                    else if (((MyWeighting)u).Selected && !((MyWeighting)u).TypeWeighting)
                        brutto = ((MyWeighting)u).Mass;       
                }


                return (brutto - tara).ToString();

                //str = str.Cast<MyWeighting>().ToArray();
                //string output = (str.Where(r => 
                //    r.Selected && 
                //    !r.TypeWeighting
                //    ).First().Mass - 
                //    str.Where(r => 
                //        r.Selected && 
                //        r.TypeWeighting
                //        ).First().Mass).ToString();
                //return output;
            }
            catch
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

My question is simple. **How I can recounting difference in group header without ListCollectionView.Refresh()???** Thanks for help.

UPD:
I'm trying to use MultyBinding:

```
<Label FontSize="13" Grid.Column="3" FontFamily="Calibri" Foreground="#FF3D3A2B" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                                                            <Label.Content>
                                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GroupConverter}">
                                                                    <Binding Path="Items"/>
                                                                    <Binding Path="WeightingsList" Source="{x:Reference FormBase1}"/>   
                                                                </MultiBinding>
                                                            </Label.Content>
                                                        </Label>
```

Converter Code:

```
public class GroupConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                var weights = values[0] as IEnumerable<object>;
                if (weights == null)
                    return "";
                var Weight = (MyWeighting)weights.First();

                var masses = (ObservableCollection<MyWeighting>)values[1];

                return (masses.Where(r => r.CarNumber == Weight.CarNumber && r.TypeWeighting == false).First().Mass - masses.Where(r => r.CarNumber == Weight.CarNumber && r.TypeWeighting == true).First().Mass).ToString();

            }
            catch
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

But label content doesn't refresh when i am changing the ObservableCollection...

UPD2:
Checkbox clearing when nearly check box is set:

```
private void CheckBox_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var State = ((CheckBox)e.Source).IsChecked;
            var Weighting4Car = (MyWeighting)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
            if ((bool)State)
            {
                foreach (var Car in WeightingsList.Where(r => r.CarNumber == Weighting4Car.CarNumber && r.TypeWeighting == Weighting4Car.TypeWeighting).ToArray())
                {
                    Car.Selected = Car.DateWeighting == Weighting4Car.DateWeighting ? true : false; // I see this changes at DataGrid
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Weighting4Car.Selected = true;
            }
}
```

Comment: you can create a multibinding and bind to one extra field, and change the field so the binding evaluates again.

Comment: Thanks for You reply. But it doesn't work... :(

Comment: More information is in updated post

Comment: you would probably be adding or removing items from `WeightingsList` that will not trigger the binding, binding is only triggered upon property change. so perhaps add a bool field and change it every time you want binding to be triggered

Comment: I don't change a quantity of elements in WeightingsList. I set/clear checkboxes in DataGridCheckBoxColumn. I set checkbox manually and clear nearby checkbox in Code. The commennts added to the post.

Comment: And I see changes at DataGrid. CheckBoxes are cleared by the code... But label in GroupHeader is unchanged...